# Appendix Scrartcl with appendix package and section size

Tags: appendices, appendix, scrartcl

For a smaller report I have switched from scrrprt to scrrartcl.
Using the appendix package the title "appendix" looks fine within toc (no number or letter preceeding; the sub-appendices however should be preceded by a letter). However the size of the actual title on the very appendix page matches the one for chapters (instead of sections). How would I be able to keep the format "Appendix" (without preceeding letter or number) in section format?

Thank you very much!
 MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,headings=standardclasses,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.00cm, footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{isodate}
\usepackage[ngerman]{datetime}
\renewcommand\sectionformat
  {%
    \mbox
      {%
        \thesection \autodot
        \IfUsePrefixLine{}{\enskip $|$\enskip}%
     }%
  }
\usepackage[ngerman]{datetime}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd\sectionformat
  {\def\autodot{.}} % replace \autodot by a fixed dot for chapter headings
  {}{\cfPatchFailed} %
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-2\baselineskip, % line spacing
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip,
  tocentrynumberformat=\def\autodot{.} % replace \autodot by a fixed dot for chapter entries
   ]{section}

\KOMAoptions{toc=sectionentrydotfill}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\renewcommand\appendixtocname{Anhang}
\renewcommand\appendixpagename{Anhang}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
    \setcounter{page}{2}
\pagebreak
\section{example section}
\begin{appendices}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}} %A
\subsection{Images}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: Please read [Wie setzt man korrekt einen Anhang?](https://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/19227/wie-setzt-man-korrekt-einen-anhang/19229) (German)

But here is a suggestion for the desired result without package `appendix`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,headings=standardclasses,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.00cm, footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{isodate}
\usepackage[ngerman]{datetime}% outdated, successor is datetime2
\renewcommand\sectionformat{\mbox{\thesection.\enskip$|$\enskip}}% <- changed
\usepackage[ngerman]{datetime}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=2\baselineskip,% changed to a positive value, if afterindent=false is set (needs version 3.26b)
  afterindent=false,% < - added, needs version 3.26b
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip,
  tocentrynumberformat=\def\autodot{.} % replace \autodot by a fixed dot for section entries
   ]{section}

\KOMAoptions{toc=sectionentrydotfill}
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\contentsname}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}

\newcommand*\appendixmore{% see the KOMA-Script documentation
  \clearpage
  \addsec{\appendixname}%
  \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\section{example section}
\appendix
\subsection{Images}
\end{document}
```

I have changed your redefinition of `\sectionformat`: sections never use a prefixline and I have replaced `\autodot` by `.` and removed the later patch of `\sectionformat`.

[image: screenshot]